# Export PNG images with alpha channel from flash

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

I have this FLA with animation and when played, the animation has alpha channel. I can’t understand why when I look in the library I see the frames without the alpha channel and also when I try to export/extract the image, again the image don’t have alpha channel.

How is it that in flash this image has alpha channel and how to get it out like that into PNG?

Here is the link to download the FLA:

[Untitled%20-1.fla](http://download759.mediafire.com/nb749r29220g/e0636ab0ru6ouoa/Untitled%20-1.fla)

Comment: The file is no longer on MediaFire. Please re-upload and post a comment to let me know when you have.